# Create JSON string in c#

Tags: c#, json

I am new to JSON format. I want to create following by using c#, Json.net.

**Target Json format:**

```
{
   "tafsir":{
      "1_1":{
         "text":"Some text here"
      },
      "1_2":{
         "text":"Some text here2"
      }
   }
}
```

But, getting output:

```
"{\"tafsir\":{\"1_1\":\"Some text here\",\"1_2\":\"Some text here2\"}}
```

I following so far, which does not give create desired json string:

```
void Main()
{
    var result = new Translation();
    Dictionary<string, string> texts = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    texts.Add("1_1", "Some text here");
    texts.Add("1_2", "some text here2");

    result.tafsir = texts;
    var jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
}

public class Translation
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> tafsir { get; set; }
}

public class Trans
{
    public List<TransItem> Texts { get; set; }
}

public class TransItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So what is its output? What doesn't work?

Comment: Your `Trans` and `TransItem` classes never come into play.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Please see the question again. I have updated it.

Comment: Where do you think the `"text":` parts will come from?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Thats a good question. I am not sure how should I rewrite the code get the target output. Do you have some ideas? Thanks

Comment: Invalid close reason. This is about reverse engineering a JSon string, not about debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var obj = new {tafsir = new Dictionary<string, object>{
                          {"1_1", new{text="Some text here"}},
                          {"1_2", new{text="Some text here2"}}
                        }
              };

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj,  Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```